# Can I save chapter titles when ripping a DVD?

Tags: video, dvd, disk-ripping

I've got a DVD set of the Live 8 concerts in 2005 which has 4 DVDs, each about 2 hours long. It's got lots of chapters markers and I want to rip them to MKV files ***and add in the artist / song titles*** when I do it.

Is there any way to do that? If so, which video player would display the chapter titles?

I'm thinking of *something along the lines of* cue sheets for flac files and wondering if there's an analagous config for video files.

Is there any way of having one big Matroshka mkv file and at the samtime, all the artists and songs identified within it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Chapters** are a native functionality of `mp4` or `mkv` containers, whatever the *encoding* you use in them. So there is no need for a separate *cue file sheet*.

You can use `handbrake` to rip your *DVD*. It supports chapters by default, and will generate them in your output file (mp4 or mkv) automatically. When you rip the DVD, you can edit the chapter names in the 'Chapters' tag.

Any decent player should support chapters. In `vlc` to jump between chapters, use the Playback menu -> Chapters sub-menu. I think Totem/Videos should also be able to use them.

Comment: I just spent ages typing in the correct chapter names from the DVD sleeve, because "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2" etc is pretty useless. So my next question is, is there an equivalent of CDDB for DVD chapter names, and software that will let me download the correct set for each DVD automatically before ripping? (I can't believe `vlc` does that - or does it???)